# IP messenger using websockets

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, ip, messenger

```
I m trying to build an ip messenger for our college in php  using websockets 
with some success but when scaled to multiple users it failed .
It's throwing out the error that no socket resource was given in parameter for socket_select but that's not true .
also if somebody could properly explain the process of handshake in depth .thanking you in advance .Here's the code of the php server.    



   <?php 

$host = ''//server ip;
echo $host;
$port = 9000;

if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) )){
    $errcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errcode);
    die("couldn't create socket [$errcode]:$errormsg");
}
echo "successfully created the socket \n";

if(!socket_bind($sock, $host,$port)){
   $errcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errcode);
    die("couldn't bind socket to ip [$errcode]:$errormsg"); 
}

echo "successfully binded the socket to given ip\n";


if(!socket_listen($sock,10)){
    $errcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errcode);
    die("socket is deaf  [$errcode]:$errormsg");
}

echo "socket started listening\n";
echo "waiting for incoming connections...\n";

$clients = array($sock);
$address_clients = array('127.0.0.1');
//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (true) {
    //manage multiple connections
    $changed = $clients;
    //returns the socket resources in $changed array
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);
    //check for new socket
    if (in_array($sock, $changed)) {
        $socket_new = socket_accept($sock); //accept new socket
        $clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array
        $found_socket = array_search($socket_new, $clients);
        $header = socket_read($socket_new,1024); //read data sent by the socket
        perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

        socket_getpeername($socket_new, $address,$port); //get ip address of connected socket
        $address_clients[$found_socket] = $address;
        echo "Client[$address] connected to us on port $port\n";
        //make room for new socket
        $found_socket = array_search($sock, $changed);
        unset($changed[$found_socket]);

    }

    /*loop through all connected sockets*/

   foreach($clients as $socketm){   
        //check for any incomming data
        while(socket_recv($socketm, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)
        {
            $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
            $received = explode(',', $received_text);

            echo $received[0]."\t".$received[1]."\n";
            $found_socket = array_search($received[1], $address_clients);
            echo $found_socket; //prepare data to be sent to client
            socket_write($clients[$found_socket], mask($received[0]),strlen(mask($received[0])));
            break 2; //exit this loop
        }

        $buf = @socket_read($socketm, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
            // remove client for $clients array
            $found_socket = array_search($socketm, $clients);
            socket_getpeername($socketm, $address);
            unset($clients[$found_socket]);

            echo "Client[$address] disconnected\n";
        }
    }
 }




 function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port)
 {
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
        {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-     
             C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
    return $upgrade;
}

function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Encode message for transfer to client.
function mask($text)
{
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}

?>
```

I m actually trying to build a better and more useful social network than facebook(no adds ,no cookies).i am using websockets instead of traditional php,ajax,sql(long -polling ) which is much slower.any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my answer if anybody in the future wants to work with websockets .I hope my answer will help them a lot saving a hard googling time .

```
<?php 

$a = @$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$host = $a;
$port = 9000;

if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) )){
    $errcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errcode);
    die("couldn't create socket [$errcode]:$errormsg");
}
echo "successfully created the socket \n";

if(!socket_bind($sock, $host,$port)){
   $errcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errcode);
    die("couldn't bind socket to ip [$errcode]:$errormsg"); 
}

echo "successfully binded the socket to given ip\n";


if(!socket_listen($sock,10)){
    $errcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errcode);
    die("socket is deaf  [$errcode]:$errormsg");
}

echo "socket started listening\n";
echo "waiting for incoming connections...\n";
$clients = array($sock);
$address_clients = array('127.0.0.1');
//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (true) {
    //manage multiple connections
    $changed = $clients;
    //returns the socket resources in $changed array
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0);
    //check for new socket
    if (in_array($sock, $changed)) {
        $socket_new = socket_accept($sock); //accept new socket
        $clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array
        $found_socket = array_search($socket_new, $clients);
        $header = socket_read($socket_new,1024); //read data sent by the socket
        perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

        socket_getpeername($socket_new, $address,$port); //get ip address of connected socket
        $address_clients[$found_socket] = $address;
        $found_socket = array_search($sock, $changed);


        echo "Client[$address] connected to us on port $port\n";
        //make room for new socket
        unset($changed[$found_socket]);

        for($i=1;$i<count($clients);$i++) {
            $message = "Client[$address] connected to us on port $port\n";
            socket_write($clients[$i], mask($message),strlen(mask($message)));
        }


    }

    //loop through all connected sockets
    foreach($changed as $changed_socket){   
        //check for any incomming data

        while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)
        {
            $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
            $received = explode(',', $received_text);

            echo $received[0]."\t".$received[1]."\n";
            $found_socket = array_search($received[1], $address_clients);
            echo $found_socket; //prepare data to be sent to client
            socket_write($clients[$found_socket], mask($received[0]),strlen(mask($received[0])));
            break 2; //exit this loop
        }

        $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
            // remove client for $clients array
            $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
            socket_getpeername($clients[$found_socket], $address);
            unset($clients[$found_socket]);

            echo "Client[$address] disconnected\n";
        }

    }
}

function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port)
{
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
        {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
    return $upgrade;
}

function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Encode message for transfer to client.
function mask($text)
{
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}
```

?>